# Publish .pbix file, Rest Api in power bi, a request with the header and the body using post import

Tags: powerbi, rest

Someone can share with me an example of how using the post import request,what to make in the header and the body,to publish a .pbix file in power bi service.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Power Query function Web.Contents you can specify the Header of the request and change its method to POST.

See function documentation:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents](https://kohera.be/power-bi/the-hidden-gems-of-the-function-web-contents/)

On this link there some examples of the function usage:

[Function Web.Contents usage examples](https://kohera.be/power-bi/the-hidden-gems-of-the-function-web-contents/)